# Where to start to create a wireless infrared hdmi cable?

Tags: wireless-networking, hdmi, hdcp

What I want to do is be able to modify or create my own wireless HDMI infrared transmitter and receiver to be able to stream media/content or whatever. I have intermediate skills in various programming languages and electronics. Please don't tell me is not practical/possible or do-able, but where could I even start, with what materials or how do you even find the source code for HDCP to be able to understand how it works or modify it? And if this is not possible for whatever reason, how do other companies/people who use this technology even get the information or the 'how-to' to make their own products, regardless whether it's what I want to do or just their own version of the standard cable? I've endlessly harassed google searching for information or any kind of basic tutorials or anything even small to get me started, but I cannot even get my foot out the door with it. Please, how could I, not why can't I.

Comment: Your question is out of scope.  We cannot help you design this hardware, and there isn’t a SE community, for this question.  You don’t have any of the required information for anyone to help you in the few communities where this could have been within scope

Comment: This isn't really on-topic for the site.  But the bandwidth on common IR components is pretty low.  It's typically used to send a few digits worth of data.  It's great if you want to experiment, but inexpensive components from Radio Shack probably won't get you near the range to stream media.

Comment: Your question is confusing you want to know if it’s possible, but don’t want to be told it isn’t possible, which is a contradiction

Comment: @fixer1234 Like you said, radio shack components probably aren't going to help me, I'm not looking for a solution. I'm looking for a place to start, resources to learn, or any direction at all.

Comment: For general information to get started, Google is your friend.  If that produces specific questions, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ might be a place to ask those.  None of the Stack Exchange sites are really designed to help with general learning questions, where you want to start from scratch and get into a subject area.  BTW, on all SE sites, you'll get a better reception with politeness.  The motto of all the sites is "Be nice."  :-)

Comment: You can't create a wireless cable. Just by definition alone.

Comment: This question is off topic and will be closed.  However, I will say one thing, IR will not work.  IR transmitters are slow and used for small bits of information being transferred serially.  Thats why its used for remote controls - to send small bits of information to a TV or DVD player.  HDMI sends massive amounts of data in parallel.  Think of it this way, it would be like 20 remote controls sending information to 20 DVD players, the IR communication would be to slow and the signals would interfere with each other.  RF transmission is better and there are  HDMI products that do that.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_Data_Association

GigaIR which is giga bit which even that isnt't enough for hdmi.

"distances up to 3m".

" The typical sweet spot for IrDA communications is from 5 to 60 cm (2.0 to 23.6 in) "

"device’s receiver is blinded by the light of its own transmitter, and thus full-duplex communication is not feasible."
 here: http://www.irda.org/

HDMI 1.0 allows a maximum TMDS clock of 165 MHz (4.95 Gbit/s bandwidth per link)  Also it lack DVD quality audio.

Even that is nearly beyond the most advanced IrDa tech.

Here is another resource:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison

The irda.org website says an international organization is developing 5 to 10gbps bandwidth but does not give any time lines.  The work may or not be abandon.  If you can get the 10gbps bandwidth you might be able to get hdmi 1.3 under the best conditions.

The latest board meeting was Tuesday, October 15, 2013 so it seems they are dead.

Chasing down some irda wikipedia links 
https://books.google.com/books?id=xodkPAAACAAJ&dq=9780975389201&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil6PzJ2OrYAhWlS98KHS04AVMQ6AEIKTAA

Aug 14 2016, 11:52am
https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/nz74gm/researchers-set-new-record-for-data-transmission-using-led-light
This novel technique makes white light out of blue light, allowing for data rates of up to 2 GB/s.

https://www.tue.nl/en/university/news-and-press/news/17-03-2017-wi-fi-on-rays-of-light-100-times-faster-and-never-overloaded/#top
Requiring an array of fibre optics in the ceiling.

You will have to make contact with these people to see if they will share there research.

My thoughts with a range of approx 4ft this whole effort seems impractical and a waste of time.  Also that is in a laboratory with high end equipment. I would say a minimum useful range is 20ft and we are years away from that.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15818/fastest-way-of-doing-on-off-modulation-of-a-led
Note above link from 2014 so newer methods probably exist, but its a starting point.

PS.  Your GoogleFu is weak I found all of this in 30min

https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/vlncomm-introduces-the-worlds-most-advanced-li-fi-usb-adapter-300574512.html

108mbps and its a real product to bad its orders of magnitude to slow.

https://www.fraunhofer.de/en/research/fields-of-research/communication-knowledge/broadband-communications/visible-light-communication.html
Still need to go 10x faster.

Here it is:
http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/lifi-internet-breakthrough-224gbps-connection-broadcast-led-bulb-1488204
"The link operates over ~3 m range at 224 Gb/s (6 x 37.4 Gb/s) and 112 Gb/s (3 x 37.4 Gb/s) with a wide field of view (FOV) of 60° and 36°, respectively. To the best of our knowledge, this is the first demonstration of a wireless link of this type with a FOV that offers practical room-scale coverage," the report states.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6967750/?reload=true&arnumber=6967750

After even more sifting of the internet

https://www.lifi.eng.ed.ac.uk/lifi-news/2015-11-28-1320/how-fast-can-lifi-be

Laser based white LEDs with a diffuser to create a broad light beam could transmit up to 100 Gbps (https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-23-2-1627  and https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/semiconductors/optoelectronics/laser-lifi-could-blast-100-gigabits-per-second).

> In research published in Optics Express, Haas and his team showed that
>   replacing the LEDs with off-the-shelf laser diodes vastly improved the
>   situation. Lasers, with their high energy and optical efficiency, can
>   be modulated at 10 times the rate of LEDs. And rather than using
>   phosphors, laser lighting would create white light by mixing the
>   output of several lasers operating at different wavelengths. That
>   means each wavelength can be used as a separate data channel, the same
>   sort of wavelength division multiplexing that lets optical
>   telecommunications carry so much data. The Edinburgh group’s
>   experiment used nine laser diodes.

Comment: This is a decent Answer. OP's biggest problem is that HDMI is 5-18Gbps, and there are no wireless IR transceivers on the market that meet those rates. Dr. Joanne Oh's work at Eindhoven University of Technology in the Netherlands shows that this is PhD level, technical university lab level stuff right now, not consumer technology that some dude with no EE could cobble together in his garage. OP's apparently hoping a 3-paragraph Answer on SuperUser can take the place of a PhD in Optics.  Good luck with that, OP.